# сглаживание в шейдере (glsl, opengl)

Tags: opengl, glsl

Нужна помощь с реализацией алгоритма сглаживания.

Что есть:
Текстура и буфер глубины (уже отрендеренной сцены, sampler2DMS).

Простой GLSL шейдер который я использую для сглаживания:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform int samples;
uniform int width;
uniform int heigth;
uniform sampler2DMS  screenTextureMS;
uniform sampler2DMS  depthTextureMS;

void main()
{ 

    color = vec4(0.0f);
    ivec2 tex = ivec2(TexCoords.x * width, TexCoords.y * heigth);

    vec4 colormas[16];
    float depthmas[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < samples  ; i++)
    {   
        depthmas[i] = texelFetch(depthTextureMS, tex, i).x;
        colormas[i] = texelFetch(screenTextureMS, tex, i);
        color += colormas[i];
    }

    color = color / samples;
}
```

Помощь нужна с тем, где найти алгоритмы сглаживания на основе мультисемплинка, тот же самый MSAA - в гугле одна чушь, и ни где не найти описание самого алгоритма.

В общем хелп.